# LocalStack with cdk is not deploying directory to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, localstack

I'm using LocalStack and CDK to test locally on my machine. I'm using the cli tool `cdklocal` (which is provided by localstack) to convert my cdk stack to a localstack.

I'm trying to create an s3 bucket as a static website and deploy content to it. Below is my cdk stack:

```
const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'bucket', {
  websiteIndexDocument: 'index.html',
  publicReadAccess: true,
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
});

new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'website', {
  sources: [s3deploy.Source.asset('./app/build')],
  destinationBucket: bucket
});
```

It should create a bucket and then deploy the contents of `./app/build` to that bucket. This works just fine when I deploy to my AWS account with `cdk deploy`. However, when I deploy to localstack with `cdklocal deploy` the bucket is created but the contents of `./app/build` is not in the bucket.

How can I use localstack to host a static website using cdk?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too. Delving into the way s3deploy.BucketDeployment works it seems that CloudFormation in AWS must trigger the deployment lambda with some sort of event and in localstack this step doesn't happen.

Looking at the logs around the deployment lambda the event appears to have this shape:

```
{
  "RequestType": "Create",
  "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1: 000000000000:function:localEnvironmentStack-CustomCDKBucketDeploymen-123abc456",
  "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1: 000000000000:stack/localEnvironmentStack/123456-abcdef-123456",
  "RequestId": "123456-abcdef-123456",
  "LogicalResourceId": "localClientDeploymentCustomResourceABCD1234",
  "ResourceType": "Custom: :CDKBucketDeployment",
  "ResourceProperties": {
    "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1: 000000000000:function:localEnvironmentStack-CustomCDKBucketDeploymen-6789defgh",
    "Prune": "true",
    "SystemMetadata": {
      "acl": "public-read"
    },
    "SourceBucketNames": [
      "cdk-abcdefgh-assets-000000000000-eu-west-1"
    ],
    "DestinationBucketName": "my-local-bucket",
    "DestinationBucketKeyPrefix": "local/",
    "SourceObjectKeys": [
    "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.zip"
    ]
  },
  "ResponseURL": "http://somecloudfrontURL.com"
}
```

I found that by downloading the deployed template with [awslocal](https://github.com/localstack/awscli-local).

```
awslocal cloudformation get-template --stack-name localEnvironmentStack --region eu-west-1
```

And then mapping some of my stacks properties into the event fields before  sending this into local stack deployed my artefacts to s3. You can run events into local stacklambda's like so:

```
awslocal lambda invoke \
        --function-name localEnvironmentStack-CustomCDKBucketDeploymen-123abc456 \
        --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
        --invocation-type Event \
        --payload '{"RequestType":"Create","ServiceToken":"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1: 000000000000:function:localEnvironmentStack-CustomCDKBucketDeploymen-123abc456","StackId":"arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1: 000000000000:stack/localEnvironmentStack/123456-abcdef-123456","RequestId":"123456-abcdef-123456","LogicalResourceId":"localClientDeploymentCustomResourceABCD1234","ResourceType":"Custom: :CDKBucketDeployment","ResourceProperties":{"ServiceToken":"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1: 000000000000:function:localEnvironmentStack-CustomCDKBucketDeploymen-6789defgh","Prune":"true","SystemMetadata":{"acl":"public-read"},"SourceBucketNames":["cdk-abcdefgh-assets-000000000000-eu-west-1"],"DestinationBucketName":"my-local-bucket","DestinationBucketKeyPrefix":"local/","SourceObjectKeys":["123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.zip"]},"ResponseURL":"http://somecloudfrontURL.com"}' \
        response.json
```

My next steps are to automate this so that after a [cdklocal](https://github.com/localstack/aws-cdk-local) deploy to localstack I can mimic the deployment events that CloudFormation must trigger during deployment. I'll also raise this as an issue over on [localstack's issues](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues).

Comment: Not a bad fix, but for me, I just run`awslocal s3 cp my-build-folder s3://my-build-bukcet --recursive` after my `cdklocal deploy`